# Apply a function over several columns

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am trying to use values from a look up table, to multiply corresponding values in a main table.

This is an example of some data

The look up

```
lu = structure(list(year = 0:12, val = c(1.6422, 1.6087, 1.5909, 1.4456, 
1.4739, 1.4629, 1.467, 1.4619, 1.2588, 1.1233, 1.1664, 1.1527, 
1.2337)), .Names = c("year", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Main data

```
dt = structure(list(year = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 
1L), x = 1:10, y = 1:10), .Names = c("year", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I can produce the results I want by merging and then multiplying one column at a time

```
library(data.table) 

dt = merge(dt, lu, by = "year")
dt[, xnew := x*val][, ynew := y*val]
```

However, I have many variables to apply this over. There have been *many* questions on this, but I cannot get it to work.

Using ideas from [How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table) , and [R Datatable, apply a function to a subset of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783598/r-datatable-apply-a-function-to-a-subset-of-columns) , I tried

```
dt[, (c("xnew", "ynew")):=lapply(.SD, function(i) i* val), .SDcols=c("x", "y")]
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'val' not found

```
for (j in c("x", "y")) set(dt, j = j, value = val* dat[[j]])
```

> Error in set(dt, j = j, value = val * dt[[j]]) : object 'val' not found

And just trying the multiplication without assigning (from [Data table - apply the same function on several columns to create new data table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879724/data-table-apply-the-same-function-on-several-columns-to-create-new-data-table)) also didnt work.

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(i) i* val), .SDcols=c("x", "y")]
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'val' not found

Please could you point out my error. Thanks.

Im using data.table version v1.9.6.

Comment: It works for me. Did you update to the latest version of `data.table`? (which is 1.10.4)

Comment: Im at v1.9.6. I can update on my home PC to try Akrun's answer, however, I will be restricted to v1.9.6 at work. (didnt think version would be an issue as the other questions were a couple of years old). Ill add details to the question.

Comment: It should work in 1.9.6 as well AFAIK

Comment: @Jaap ; okay thanks. I reinstalled v1.9.6 again and the code in the Q is working. (bit embarrassed must have been something local to my pc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try by join and then by specifying `.SDcols`

```
dt[lu, on = .(year), nomatch =0 
    ][, c("x_new", "y_new") := lapply(.SD, `*`, val), .SDcols = x:y][]
```

Comment: thanks. *could not find function "."* . I'll update my package version

Comment: @user2957945 if you have trouble in installing the new version, try with `https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation` to get the devel version